# Which binaries should be available for the user to change password via ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, restricted

I have a user that has a `rbash` as default shell (in order to limit his privileges). I also changed his default `bin` directory to cut-off most binaries from his `PATH`. User should time to time change his password. So which binaries should be reachable to give him the possibility to change password via ssh. I created a symbolic link to `passwd` in his bin directory but he still can't change password using ssh.

Comment: `passwd` is at `/usr/bin/passwd`.  He should have access to that file (and the subdirectories up to that file).  A symbolic link alone won't help if he doesn't have access to the file that the symbolic link points to.  i.e., A symbolic link doesn't bypass the permissions on the file.

Comment: @Ray He has access to all sub-directories. Unfortunately it didn't help. I'm still investigating problem.

Comment: Is it needed to do that? `passwd` has an option `--expire` and that would force inserting a new passwrd

Comment: What is the actual error behavior you are observing? I just tried it in a WSL instance and it seemed to work

Comment: I suppose you can try running `passwd` through `strace` (i.e., `strace passwd`) and see if it's trying to load other files.  I only have a rudimentary knowledge of `strace`, so you'll have to read up on it; `passwd` could be loading shared libraries which you have taken away his access to.

Answer (score 1):

A user in a restricted bash shell should be able to successfully run the [`passwd`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/passwd.1.html) command as long as they have the location(*full path of containing directory*) of a working `passwd` binary in their search path.

That is the usual with [`rbash`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/rbash.1.html) as the restrictions by default apply only to:

> •      changing directories with cd
>
> •      setting or unsetting the values of SHELL, PATH, ENV, or
> BASH_ENV
>
> •      specifying command names containing /
>
> •      specifying a filename containing a / as an argument to the .
> builtin command
>
> •      specifying a filename containing a slash as an argument to
> the  -p  option  to  the
> hash builtin command
>
> •      importing function definitions from the shell environment at
> startup
>
> •      parsing the value of SHELLOPTS from the shell environment at
> startup
>
> •      redirecting output using the >, >|, <>, >&, &>, and >>
> redirection operators
>
> •      using the exec builtin command to replace the shell with
> another command
>
> •      adding  or  deleting  builtin  commands  with  the  -f and
> -d options to the enable
> builtin command
>
> •      using the enable builtin command to enable disabled shell
> builtins
>
> •      specifying the -p option to the command builtin command
>
> •      turning off restricted mode with set +r or set +o
> restricted.

If,however, you are adding some extra strict measures other than using `rbash` as the user's shell, you might want to look at what `passwd` actually needs to access, open, or write to with [`strace`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/strace.1.html) like so:

```bash
strace -e open,openat,write,access passwd
```